# Como checar se uma determinada sequencia de elements existe no R?

Tags: r

tenho um vetor como esse:

```
vectorx<-c(3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

e quero checar se a sequência 3,3,1,1,1,2 existe.
Acontece que essa sequência pode estar em qualquer posição do vetor, só quero saber se especificamente essa sequencia desse jeito existe, quero que ele retorne TRUE ou FALSE somente. Como faço? Vejo muitos %in% mas para uma sequência que pode ocorrer em qualquer posição não vi ainda.
Obrigada pessoal

Comment: Um pacote útil para problemas desse tipo é o TraMineR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Library(zoo)

vectory <- c(3,3,1,1,1,2)

which(rollapply(vectorx, length(vectory), identical, vectory))
```

Se a saída for algum número, a sequência `vectory` está presente no `vectorx`; caso contrário o resultado será `integer(0)`

Comment: Excelente Willian, é exatamente isso. Muito obrigada

Comment: Você conhece um jeito de retornar TRUE ao invés de integer(0)?
R: Já resolvi, só tirei o which

Answer (score 4):

Eu sei que a resposta já foi aceita, mas como deseja uma resposta do tipo `TRUE` ou `FALSE` segue uma alternativa:

```
vectorx <- c(3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
vectory <- c(3,3,1,1,1,2)

grepl(paste(vectory, collapse = " "), paste(vectorx, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: Funciona muito bem também, inclusive fico me culpando aqui porque eu conhecia grepl rsrs. Muitíssimo obrigada